# static public vs public static

Tags: php, object

Is static public vs public static the same in functionality?  (I use PHP)

```
class Car{
    static public $break='strong break';
    public static $maxspeed=100;
}
```

Is it just for reading easier by using the first one?

Comment: [“public static” or “static public”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/757424/2518525)

Comment: Whatever you want by write it with the same order always.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no difference between static public and public static. The order of the keywords doesn't matter in this situation, use whatever you think will be more easily read.

Comment: Neither is syntactically incorrect, however, 99% of the code out there uses `public static` vs the other way. And makes sense, you immediately see the scope of the member.

Answer (score 0):

It just for a variable permission or define as variable behaviour, keyword 'public' and 'static' are allowed to used in different order, output will be the same.